# Access Violation Reading Location: Linked List c++

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

I am trying to do a linked list of int values. I add 3 int values to list, and I print them but my problem after print the 3 values, the program goes back in to print function to print a 4th one because (tempNode != NULL) gives true but it should be NULL after printing 3 values, so it gives me access violation reading error in the print method at `cout << "index " << size-- << ", value: "<< tempNode->num << endl;`

It is going beyond my list nodes, but I have no idea where am doing wrong.

Please help, 2 days am trying to figure this out.

code below.

```
IntList::IntList()
{
    first = NULL;
    last = NULL;
    size = 0;
}


 IntList::Node::Node(const int& info, Node* next = NULL)
 {
    num = info;
    next = next;
 }


 IntList::~IntList()
 {
    Node* tempNode = first;
    while ( tempNode != NULL )
    //for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        Node* nextNode = tempNode->next;
        delete tempNode;
        tempNode = nextNode;
    }

    first = last = NULL;
    size = 0;
  }


IntList::IntList(const IntList& wl)
{
     cout << "here word list copy conts " << endl;

     first = last = NULL;
     size = wl.size;
     if(wl.first != NULL){

        Node* tempNode = wl.first;
        for(int i = 0; i < wl.size; i++)
        {
              addLast(tempNode->num);
              tempNode = tempNode->next;
        }
     }
}


IntList& IntList::operator = (const IntList& wl)
{
    cout << "here word list =" << endl;
    if(this == &wl)
        return *this;

    Node* tempNode = first;
    while ( tempNode != NULL )
    {
        Node* nextNode = tempNode->next;
        delete tempNode;
        tempNode = nextNode;
    }

    first = NULL;
    last = NULL;

    if(wl.first != NULL)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < wl.size; i++)
        {
           addLast(tempNode->num);
           tempNode = tempNode->next;
           size++;
    }
}

return *this;
}

 void IntList::addFirst(int& winfo)
{
    Node* firstNode = new Node(winfo);
    //Node firstNode(winfo);
    if(first == NULL) 
    {
        first = last = firstNode;
    }
    else 
    {
        firstNode->next = first;
        first = firstNode;  
    }
    //increment list size
    size++;
}

void IntList::print(ostream& out)
{
    Node* tempNode = first;
    while ( tempNode != NULL )
    {
        out << "\t";
        cout << "index " << size-- << ", value: "<< tempNode->num << endl;
        tempNode = tempNode->next;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Can you please reduce this to a *minimal* but complete example that demonstrates the problem you're having?  Prefereably something we can compile & run without having to modify it.

Comment: I can provide my header file, is that ok?

Comment: It would be best if you could write a complete program, including a `main()` function, of no more than say 50 or so lines, that replicates the problem you're having. This will make it much easier for us to help you.  As a helpful side-effect, you may even find the problem yourself doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `next` parameter of the `Node` constructor shadows its `next` member, so `next = next` is assigning to the parameter.
Rename one of them.

Also, don't modify `size` while you're printing.